# Expected squared Error (bagging)

Tags: statistics, expected-value, machine-learning

I'm studying from a Deep Learning book (Ian Goodfellow et al).
At page 256 the text explains that, considering a set of $k$ regression models, each produces an error $ϵ_i$​ for every example, drawn from a zero-mean multivariate normal distribution with variances $E[ϵ_i^2]=v$ and covariances $E[ϵ_iϵ_j]=c$. Then the error made by the average prediction of all the ensemble models is $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i$.
The expected squared error of the ensemble predictor is:

$
\begin{align*}
E\left[\left(\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i\right)^2\right] &= \frac{1}{k^2} E\left[\sum_{i=1}^k (\epsilon_i)^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} \epsilon_i \epsilon_j\right] \
&= \frac{1}{k} v + \frac{k-1}{k} c.
\end{align*}
$$

So, the question is: How do we obtain the first quadratic decomposition? I'm having trouble with it.
Could someone explain?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just write it out for small $k$.  For $k=2$, say, all this claims is that $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2 +ab+ba$.  This has nothing to do with expectation, beyond the use of linearity to claim that $E\left( \frac x{k^2}\right)=\frac 1{k^2}\times E(x)$.  Of course the second equivalence uses properties of expectation.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand..

Comment: What don't you understand?  Just write it out for small $k$.  In my example, I used $a,b$ instead of $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$, but of course you should use whatever notation you like.  My point was just that there's nothing going on here but squaring.  $(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\cdots+\epsilon_n)^2=\sum \epsilon_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j} \epsilon_i\times \epsilon_j$ just as in my example with $a,b$.

Comment: If you liked, you could write that second sum as $2\sum_{i<j} \epsilon_i\times \epsilon_j$, just as $ab+ba=2ab$.  Maybe that looks more intuitive?

Comment: That's more intuitive!!! Thank you so much!